# Filter ListView ArrayList

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, filter

I'm trying for some time to create a filter in my listview, I've made several unsuccessful attempts.
In case I am trying to filter by the "bairro" field, most currently it does not return any errors so I can look for a possible solution, not symmetrically.

At the beginning of my list I already have a fixed filter that is for shows only the records with status of "PROGRAMADA" and other filter by dates.

**My last attempt:**

```
public void getOSProgramada(){
        final ArrayList<OrdemServico> lstOsProgramada = new ArrayList<>();

        if(ordem_servicoSerializado.exists()){
            try {
                ArrayList<OrdemServico> lstOS = (ArrayList<OrdemServico>) new SerializarDados().restauraDadosemArquivo(config.sARMAZENAMENTO_ARQUIVO_LOCAL, "ordem_servico");
                Usuario usu = (Usuario) new SerializarDados().restauraDadosemArquivo(config.sARMAZENAMENTO_ARQUIVO_LOCAL, "usuario");

                for(int i = 0; i < lstOS.size(); i++){
                    if(lstOS.get(i).getNid_usuario() == usu.getNid_usuario() && lstOS.get(i).getSstatus().equals("PROGRAMADA")
                            && lstOS.get(i).getSdata_programada().equals(""+config.getDataAtual())){

                        OrdemServico os = new OrdemServico();

                        os.setNnumero_os(lstOS.get(i).getNnumero_os());
                        os.setStipo(lstOS.get(i).getStipo());
                        os.setSnome(lstOS.get(i).getSnome());
                        os.setSendereco(lstOS.get(i).getSendereco());
                        os.setSstatus(lstOS.get(i).getSstatus());
                        os.setSdata_programada(lstOS.get(i).getSdata_programada());
                        os.setSdata_conclusao(lstOS.get(i).getSdata_conclusao());
                        os.setNuc(lstOS.get(i).getNuc());
                        os.setSmedidor(lstOS.get(i).getSmedidor());
                        os.setSbairro(lstOS.get(i).getSbairro());
                        os.setScidade(lstOS.get(i).getScidade());
                        os.setScomplemento(lstOS.get(i).getScomplemento());
                        os.setNsetor(lstOS.get(i).getNsetor());
                        os.setSlatitude(lstOS.get(i).getSlatitude());
                        os.setSlongitude(lstOS.get(i).getSlongitude());
                        os.setsNovaObs(lstOS.get(i).getsNovaObs());


                        lstOsProgramada.add(os);
                    }
                }

                setListAdapter(new OrdemServicoAdapter(MenuPrincipalActivity.this, lstOsProgramada));

                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                              int count) {
                        //quando o texto é alterado chamamos o filtro.
                        new OrdemServicoAdapter(MenuPrincipalActivity.this, lstOsProgramada).getFilter().filter(s.toString());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                                  int after) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    }
                });


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

**Adapter:**

```
public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence filtro) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                //se não foi realizado nenhum filtro insere todos os itens.
                final ArrayList<OrdemServico> lstOsProgramada = new ArrayList<>();

                if (filtro == null || filtro.length() == 0) {
                    results.count = lstOsProgramada.size();
                    results.values = lstOsProgramada;
                } else {
                    try {
                        ArrayList<OrdemServico> lstOS = (ArrayList<OrdemServico>) new SerializarDados().restauraDadosemArquivo(config.sARMAZENAMENTO_ARQUIVO_LOCAL, "ordem_servico");

                        //percorre toda lista verificando se contem a palavra do filtro na descricao do objeto.
                        for (int i = 0; i < lstOS.size(); i++) {
                            OrdemServico os = new OrdemServico();

                            filtro = filtro.toString().toUpperCase();
                            String condicao = lstOS.get(i).getSbairro().toUpperCase();

                            if (condicao.contains(filtro)) {
                                //se conter adiciona na lista de itens filtrados.
                                lstOsProgramada.add(os);
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    // Define o resultado do filtro na variavel FilterResults
                    results.count = lista.size();
                    results.values = lista;
                }
                return results;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {
                lista = (ArrayList<OrdemServico>) results.values; // Valores filtrados.
                notifyDataSetChanged();  // Notifica a lista de alteração
            }

        };
        return filter;
    }
```

Comment: For what are you trying to filter? If it's a list, then `list.stream().filter(predicate).collect(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never create everytime the new instance of your Adapter class, instead of that, use this:

```
adapter = new OrdemServicoAdapter(MenuPrincipalActivity.this, lstOsProgramada);
setListAdapter(adapter);

EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        //quando o texto é alterado chamamos o filtro.
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        postInvalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

And in your Adapter class use something like this:

```
private CustomFilter filter;

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null) {
        filter = new CustomFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}

private class CustomFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence filtro) {
            String searchPhrase = constraint.toString();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            //se não foi realizado nenhum filtro insere todos os itens.
            final ArrayList<OrdemServico> lstOsProgramada = new ArrayList<>();

            if (filtro == null || filtro.length() == 0) {
                results.count = lstOsProgramada.size();
                results.values = lstOsProgramada;
            } else {
                try {
                    ArrayList<OrdemServico> lstOS = (ArrayList<OrdemServico>) new SerializarDados().restauraDadosemArquivo(config.sARMAZENAMENTO_ARQUIVO_LOCAL, "ordem_servico");

                    //percorre toda lista verificando se contem a palavra do filtro na descricao do objeto.
                    for (int i = 0; i < lstOS.size(); i++) {
                        OrdemServico os = new OrdemServico();

                        filtro = filtro.toString().toUpperCase();
                        String condicao = lstOS.get(i).getSbairro().toUpperCase();

                        if (condicao.contains(filtro)) {
                            //se conter adiciona na lista de itens filtrados.
                            lstOsProgramada.add(os);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                // Define o resultado do filtro na variavel FilterResults
                results.count = lista.size();
                results.values = lista;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {
            lista = (ArrayList<OrdemServico>) results.values; // Valores filtrados.
            notifyDataSetChanged();  // Notifica a lista de alteração
        }
}
```

Comment: one last questions when I clean editText the Listview gets no record. How do I solve this?

Comment: You need to store all records as global variable in the Adapter and in statement `if (filtro == null || filtro.length() == 0) {` you need to fill results with the allRecordsArraySet, that you stored global. It's very simple.